# Templating function pointers using Maps

Tags: c++, function, templates, stl, function-pointers

I am trying to use templates to create a mapping for understanding the concepts, but I am getting an error and failed to understand what I am doing wrong.

Can anyone take a look and let me know what I am doing wrong ? Please share a working example of a design if possible which I would really appreciate.

Thanks

```
#include <iostream>
#include <map>

using namespace std;

enum MathOperations
{
    ADD = 0,
    SUBTRACT,
    MULTIPLY,
    DIVISION
};

template <typename T>
T Addition(T a, T b)
{
    return a + b;
}

template <typename T>
T Subtraction(T a, T b)
{
    return a - b;
}

template <typename T>
struct MathOp
{
    typedef T (*FuncPtr) (T, T);
};

/* I am getting a warning here, which says variable templates are c++1 extension */
template <typename T>
const std::map<MathOperations, typename MathOp<T>::FuncPtr> MathMap = {
    { MathOperations::ADD, &Addition<T> },
    { MathOperations::SUBTRACT, &Subtraction<T> }
};

int main ()
{
    MathOp<int> mathIntObj;

    /* I am getting error here */
    /* No viable overloaded operator[] for type 'const std::map<MathOperations, typename MathOp<int>::FuncPtr>' */
    std::cout << *(MathMap<int>[MathOperations::ADD])(1, 2) << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

EDIT: 
Thanks to @Piotr Skotnicki, who shared a solution for my error. 
I had to make following changes:

```
std::cout << (*MathMap<int>.at(MathOperations::ADD))(1, 2) << endl;
```

Removed

```
MathOp<int> mathIntObj;
```

Still, I need to fix the warning. Any ideas ? Thanks

Comment: Could you please copy/paste the error message? That would be useful.

Comment: There's no const overload for `map::operator[]`

Comment: Here is the error: No viable overloaded operator[] for type 'const std::map<MathOperations, typename MathOp<int>::FuncPtr>'sc - 201702190978 Thanks

Comment: use `at()` instead of `[]`.

Comment: Why are you using function pointers? Why not e.g. [`std::function`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/function)? And what use is the `MathOp` structure other than as a holder for the `FuncPtr` type-alias?

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude `std::function` are not a systematic replacement for function pointers. No need for type erasure, no need for `std::function`.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude, I wanted to create a template version of function pointer. I am trying to learn about function pointers usage in diff ways, and wanted to see if I can achieve what I want. Could you share what we can do to fix this as I am  newbie ? Thanks

Comment: @PiotrSkotnicki, I have removed const and then I get new error "Indirection requires pointer operand ('int' invalid)" I dont know what I am doing wrong. Plz suggest a fix. Thanks

Comment: `std::cout << (*MathMap<int>[MathOperations::ADD])(1, 2) << endl;`

Comment: @Jarod42, using at() did not fix. Still same error :(

Comment: @PiotrSkotnicki, This ( 
std::cout << (*MathMap<int>[MathOperations::ADD])(1, 2) << endl;)  fixed it. I did not notice this as I thought * should be outside parenthesis. Thank you very much. Would you mind sharing some feedback about my approach ? is this good or bad ? any changes that we can make it for better solution ?  Also what about warning I mentioned, Please ? Thanks

Comment: For the warning, `-std=c++11` or `-std=c++14` compilation flag should remove it.

Answer (score 0):

Why not use lambdas and the class template `std::function`, thus greatly reducing your code size:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <map>
#include <functional>

using namespace std;

enum MathOperations
{
    ADD = 0,
    SUBSTRACT,
    MULTIPLY,
    DIVISION
};

template <typename T>
const std::map<MathOperations, typename std::function<T(T,T)>> MathMap = {
    { MathOperations::ADD, [](T a, T b){ return a + b; } },
    { MathOperations::SUBSTRACT, [](T a, T b) { return a - b; } }
};

int main ()
{

    std::cout << (MathMap<int>.at(MathOperations::ADD))(3, 2) << endl;
    std::cout << (MathMap<int>.at(MathOperations::SUBSTRACT))(6, 5) << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for sharing your feedback and an example. Actually, I wanted to play around function pointers in order to understand them. So I started with this idea. May I know where you used lambdas in your example ? I see only std::function.  Also, can you tell me how to fix the warning i get with map ? Thanks

Comment: I use lambdas in the initialization of the map. In your code: Change `std::cout << *(MathMap<int>[MathOperations::ADD])(1, 2) << endl;` to `std::cout << (MathMap<int>.at(MathOperations::ADD))(1, 2) << endl;` as Jarod42 suggested and kick `MathOp<int> mathIntObj;`

Comment: Understood. Still I have that warning I mentioned with Map expression. Any idea to fix that ? Thanks

Comment: Use c++14 or maybe build a template wrapper class MathMap that defines the `[]` operator.